# Es correcta la sentencia "break" despues de un bloque try/except en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola quisiera saber si al poner `break` despues del `except` es correcto para que continue con la ejecución del programa.
A lo que voy es a esto:

```
try:
      # Instrucciones...     
except:
      # Captura el error imprimiendolo en pantalla

break 

# Siguientes instrucciones..
```

Es válido el break? Se que es una pregunta bastante sencilla pero vi que `break` lo ponen al finalizar el `try`, osea antes del `except`, y no entiendo por qué. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Las palabras reservadas `break`, `continue` solo se utilizan dentro de ciclos o loops, de lo contrario te dará un error

Comment: Se puede saber donde has visto eso? Y que es lo que quierez hacer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respondiendo a:

> Hola quisiera saber si al poner break después del `except` es correcto para que continúe con la ejecución del programa

Pues no, no es correcto tal como lo tienes. El `break` es una sentencia exclusiva para los ciclos o loops, seguramente también has visto las palabras `continue` y `pass` y estas indican los siguiente:

- `break`: Rompe el loop, haciendo que este termine.
- `continue`: Ignora el resto de instrucciones del loop y vuelve al inicio.
- `pass`: No hace nada.

La palabra `pass` no es específica de los loops o ciclos, esta se puede usar en cualquier parte y muchas veces es puesta dentro de funciones o instrucciones que aun no están terminadas. Dado que en Python no se usan las llaves para definir un bloque de código (como funciones o sentencias `if`) y simplemente se depende de la indentación, es totalmente necesario colocar algo dentro de tal bloque y no debe quedar vacío. ejemplo:
**sintaxis incorrecta**

```py
def funcion():
    #aqui va la funcion

#resto de codigo
print("hola")
```

Esto dará un error de indentación, pues Python espera que la siguiente línea tenga una sangría de 2 ó 4 espacios.
**Lo correcto sería**

```py
def funcion():
    pass #no hace nada

print("hola")
```

Con esto se soluciona el problema :D

Las sentencias `continue` y `break` se utilizan en los ciclos `for` y `while` (los cuales son loops), veamos un ejemplo:

```py
for i in range(5):
    if i%2==0:
        continue
    print(i,end="")
```

Esto imprimirá solo los números pares que estén en el rango de 0 a 4, veamos la salida.

```
0 1 3
```

Esto sucede por que al cumplirse la condición se *omite* las demás instrucciones y se vuelve al inicio del ciclo `for`.
En cuanto a `break` como dije, esto para por completo el loop y simplemente prosigue con la ejecución del programa.

```py
i = 0
while true:
    if i<5: break
    print(i,end=" ")
    i+=1
print("ha finalizado el ciclo")
```

Esto es un loop *infinito*, pero gracias a la sentencia `break` ya no lo es. Cuando la variable `i` tenga el valor de `5` el `while` terminará su ejecución (es como haber llegado al final de una iteración) y Python continuará ejecutando lo que hay despues del `while`, **no vuelve a ejecutar nada más del while**. El resultado sería:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
ha finalizado el ciclo
```

Bueno tal vez te hayas confundido un poco con lo que dije.

> [...] el `while` terminará su ejecución [...] y Python continuará ejecutando lo que hay despues del `while`

Esto **no es lo mismo** que intentas hacer con tu `try/except`, `break` solo sirve dentro de un loop, al estar dentro de uno detiene la ejecución de este, por lo que se considera que *ha finalizado* y Python, como cualquier otro lenguaje, continua ejecutando el resto del código.

Veamos un ejemplo sencillo.

```py
try:
    int(23) #esto no causará excepcion
except:
    print("hay un error")
break
```

Esto es un error de sintaxis, pues `break` no se encuentra dentro de ningún loop y por lógica tampoco lo es, pues si `break` detiene la ejecución de un loop, lo que se espera es que esté dentro del `except` en caso haya un fallo. lo correcto sería

```py
lista = [2,30,"hola", 10, "bye"]
for i in lista:
    try:
        int(i)
    except:
        print("hay un error")
        break #si hay un error paramos el ciclo
    print(i)
print("ha finalizado")
```

Esto si es correcto, pues `break` está dentro de una función y en caso de haber un error *rompe* el `for` y listo.

```
2
30
hay un error
ha finalizado
```

Comment: En mí caso tengo dos loops while y adentro del segundo while tengo el try except,  quisiera que cuando llegue a encontrar un error y salga por el except haga un break y continúe con la ejecución del código pero ahora que me dices esto solo es válido en los loops... 

Comment: Es el último ejemplo que mostré, el `break` debe de estar dentro de un loop, no importa que tenga un `trt/except` siempre que el `break` este dentro de un bloque `while` o `for` todo debe de funcionar